# How do min() and max-height differ?

Tags: css

Using the following css declartion on the same exact fluid image yields different results when resizing the screen:

```
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: min(100vh, 850px);
 object-fit: cover;
}


img {
 width: 100%;
 max-height: 850px;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

Both give a maximum height but why does it yield different results on smaller view ports?

Comment: I assume that on smaller viewports in first case height is always set at 100vh and in second case as there is no height declared it is scaled proportionally to change in width of element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make them the same you need to add `height:100vh` to the second one to have:

```
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: min(100vh, 850px);
 object-fit: cover;
}


img {
 width: 100%;
 max-height: 850px;
 height: 100vh;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```